# What is difference between return View() and return base.View()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My base controller is below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
    }
}
```

My Home controller is below:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ActionResult action = base.View("Login");
        return action;
    }
}
```

My question is what is main difference between `base.View()` and `View()`?
Is there any performance constrain or any other concern?

Answer (score 1):

> Well, it depends whether you want to call the overridden version if
>   there is one. If you absolutely know when you write the code that you
>   don't want to call an overridden version, call base.MyMethod(). If you
>   want to use whatever version has been provided by the class, call
>   this.MyMethod() or just MyMethod().

[Source](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2004-06/3176.html)

Comment: It's good that you didn't claim this text was your own, but why did you not provide a source? [Here is a link to an archived copy of Jon Skeet's message this text was copied from.](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2004-06/3176.html)

Comment: yes I know I provided this answer as Blockquote, however I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ok. If I used Base controller at that time whose call is good for better programming  practice among three calls View(),base.View()or this.View() ?

Answer (score 0):

If the View method is not overriden in BaseController - there is no difference because View will be called from Controller class.